# Schema.org for the FAQ page

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have a FAQ page and I want to do it with better html-schema.

```html
<main role="main" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <article itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
    <header>
      <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
    </header>
    <section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
      <h2 itemprop="name">Some question #1</h2>
      <p itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
        <span itemprop="text">This is an answer #1</span>
      </p>
    </section>
    <section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
      <h2 itemprop="name">Some question #2</h2>
      <p itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
        <span itemprop="text">This is an answer #2</span>
      </p>
    </section>
    <section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
      <h2 itemprop="name">Some question #3</h2>
      <p itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
        <span itemprop="text">This is an answer #3</span>
      </p>
    </section>
  </article>
</main>
```

I think a better type for the page is `FAQPage` instead of `WebPage`, but `FAQPage` has pending status and doesn't validate in Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

What do you think about this scheme? Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FAQPage`](http://schema.org/FAQPage) will be the best type for the page. If you don’t want to use it until it’s released, `WebPage` is the best alternative. You could also consider using both types for now, and remove `WebPage` as soon as `FAQPage` is part of the core vocabulary (or remove `FAQPage` if it goes to the [attic](http://attic.schema.org/)):

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage http://schema.org/FAQPage">
```

I wouldn’t use the `mainContentOfPage` property. It expects a `WebPageElement`, which is typically not useful.

In your case, the `Question` items aren’t connected to the `WebPage` item. For this, you could use the [`hasPart` property](http://pending.schema.org/hasPart).

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage http://schema.org/FAQPage">

  <section>

    <h2 itemprop="name">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>

    <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question"></article>
    <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question"></article>
    <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question"></article>

  </section>

</main>
```

(I switched the `article` and `section` elements because I think it makes more sense that way, semantically.)

Comment: I think I did right way with `article > section`, because in my case sections - it's just parts of article. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

Comment: @SergeyEroshenkov: I don’t agree if it’s a typicaly FAQ page: users don’t need to read all question/answer pairs for it to make sense, each Q/A pair stands on its own (could have its own page, its own author, its own comments, its own feed entry etc.). Both of these can be indications that `article` is appropriate for each pair, and not for the whole thing.  -- If, however, it’s not a typical FAQ page, but the question/answer pairs are integrated into an article with context (so not just a list of Q/A pairs), then `article` for the whole thing is appropriate.

Comment: As of 2019-05-07, the `FAQPage` is now an official schema extension: https://schema.org/FAQPage, https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage, and https://searchengineland.com/google-search-adds-support-for-faq-and-how-to-structured-data-316541