# Warning on 'Question' type: "Missing a QAPage markup item on page to which this item should be associated."

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

The following [`Answer`](https://schema.org/Answer) schema gives a warning in Google’s SDTT:

> Missing a *QAPage* markup item on page to which this item should be associated.

Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
    <h1 itemprop="name">What is attr_accessor in Ruby?</h1>
    <div itemprop="upvoteCount">196</div>
    <div itemprop="text">I am having difficulty understanding Ruby attr_accessors, can someone explain them?</div>
    <div>asked <time itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="2010-11-04T20:07Z">Nov 11 '10 at 20:07</time></div>
    <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <span itemprop="name">someuser</span>
    </div>
    <div><span itemprop="answerCount">4</span> answers</div>
    <div itemprop="suggestedAnswer acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
        <div itemprop="upvoteCount">1337</div>
        <div itemprop="text">
        (The text of the accepted answer goes here...).
        </div>
        <div>answered <time itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="2010-12-01T22:01Z">Dec 1 '10 at 22:01</time></div>
        <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">anotheruser</span></div>
   </div>
   <div itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
       <div itemprop="upvoteCount">39</div>
       <div itemprop="text">
      (Another explanation would go here).
   </div>
   <div>answered <time itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="2010-12-06T21:11Z">Dec 6 '10 at 21:11</time></div>
   <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">lonelyuser1234</span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is this markup not true for Google at this time?

Answer (score 3):

Like the warning says, Google recommends to provide a [`QAPage`](https://schema.org/QAPage) item, probably for qualifying for one of Google’s search result features.

You can associate your `Question` to the `QAPage` via the [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) property:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
    <!-- … -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also take in mind if this is a [`QAPage`](https://schema.org/QAPage) (which only handles an individual question as stated) or a [`FAQPage`](https://pending.schema.org/FAQPage) (with one or more questions & answers, as stated as well). The last one is still on the pending extension, but it looks it is close to be released into the schema spec, per https://searchengineland.com/google-confirms-new-faqs-qa-and-how-tos-for-search-results-snippets-303116.

In any case, you should be able to wrap all of your [`Question`](https://schema.org/Question) and [`Answer`](https://schema.org/Answer) schema markup within the markup of these other specs, at least for `QAPage` and `FAQPage`, which both extend from [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) (already stablished inside the schema spec).

You can take a look at how SO does it inside the `<html>` tag, at least for the `QAPage` spec, which seems more like the thing you need: [image]

Also, these are some SO questions that might be related to yours:

- [Schema.org for the FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48581089/2946413)
- [Schema warning about QAPage on Question type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203521/2946413)
- [QAPage with multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52036463/2946413)

**2019-05-08 - EDIT:** The `FAQPage` is now an official extension:

- https://schema.org/FAQPage
- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage
- https://searchengineland.com/google-search-adds-support-for-faq-and-how-to-structured-data-316541

Answer (score -2):

This day i was searching for something similar, in the past my html code whas ok but shcema.org is always changin. I check out your code and the erros and requirements were the same for my code. I re-write by my own the code and i have the answer.

Now if you whant to solve the problem (probably in a few months its wrong what im writing) try this

itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/FAQPage"
itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question"

REMOVE itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question" and add at the end one more div
(i have problems to copy the full code add properly de starting and ending divs

Comment: <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/FAQPage">
<div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
    <h1 itemprop="name">What is attr_accessor in Ruby?</h1>
....
   </div>
</div></div>